# How does zabbix monitor the number of open files on the server

Tags: zabbix

How does zabbix monitor the number of open files on the server? Who can tell me what to do?

Answer (score 1):

There is no native item to monitor the number of open files.

There's a feature request [here](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-3191) and you can upvote it.
Also in the same page there'are some sample items like:

`vfs.file.regexp[/proc/sys/fs/file-nr,"([0-9]+)\s+([0-9]+)\s+([0-9]+)",,1,2,\1]`

Answer (score 0):

Since version 6.0 the Zabbix agent supports this natively through the "kernel.openfiles" item key.

Oficial documentation: https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/6.0/en/manual/config/items/itemtypes/zabbix_agent